# Grit won't launch due to DLL error

Tags: windows-xp, dll

when I launch grit it gives me this error message:

interlockedcompareexchange64 could not be located in the dynamic linked library "KERNEL32.DLL"

I can't figure out if this is a problem with Windows having a missing or perhaps corrupt function from the dll, or if there's a problem with the way the engine was built. will rebuilding the program work or do I need to re-install windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message appears because Grit uses the [`InterlockedCompareExchange64()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683562(v=vs.85).aspx) function that is only available starting with Windows Vista and Server 2003 – that is, Windows XP does not yet have it.

Rebuilding Grit on a Windows XP system *may* help, if it was written to choose from alternative versions of the same task at compile time. (For example, it is usually possible to perform the same task various other synchronization functions provided by Windows XP, although several of them would have to be combined, which would be a little bit more error-prone when writing and slower when running.)

On the other hand, Windows XP *is* ~12 years old by now, so it's quite possible that the developers have chosen to not support it anymore and haven't added any such alternate code versions.

Reinstalling Windows will not help, as its libraries simply do not have this function at all.